# How to make all page elements not to react on clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to make an extension with 'pick' functionality: letting the user click on any element on the page and see the xpath for it.

However, to make it usable I have to prevent the element from reacting on clicking: I don't want clicking on hyperlinks to forward me to another page, buttons to submit forms, etc., etc.

How would I do that?

UPD: I need it only for Chrome

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support? You can easily achieve that by setting the event handler to listen in the capturing phase, but it's not supported in IE8 and below.

Comment: @FelixKling I need to support Chrome only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest way in my opinion would be to bind one event handler to `body` in the *capturing* phase and prevent the event from propagating/the default behavior.

You can get a reference to the clicked element with `event.target`:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.target);
}, true);
```

The advantage is that this event handler will be the very first that is triggered, no matter which other event handlers are bound to elements in the page (unless of course the page binds a similar event handler to `body`, but usually event handlers are bound in the bubbling phase).

For more information see [quirksmode.org - Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and [MDN - `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yVstH/)

Comment: Despite the fact that this solution is pure js and not jQuery, it seems to be the most relevant and easy to rewrite in jQuery manner. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For a CSS only solution:

```
* {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: `The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. `

Comment: The question is whether the extension's event handler will be triggered if this rule is set.

Comment: Had to test it and you are right Felix, the event handler will not fire so this isn't a solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('body *').on('click',function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You're not the real Jon Skeet

Comment: You've assumed jQuery, which might not be available.

Comment: @Mike: The question is tagged with jQuery.

Comment: Two issues with this approach (IMO): This won't prevent event handlers that are directly bound to an element and you are binding a new event handler to *every* element in the page.

Answer (score 1):

In your `click` event handler make sure you either call `preventDefault()` in the event object, or return `false` from your function. For example:

```
function myClickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault()  // e is the event object
  // Do your click stuff here
  .
  .
  .
  return false;   // not required if you've called e.preventDefault()
}
```